# Trouble setting UIView borderColor in iOS9.0

Tags: ios, uiview

I am trying to set my UIView's **layer.borderColor** property to a custom UIColor like this:

```
groupPageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:203.0 green:17.0 blue:17.0 alpha:1]
```

and it is not working. What is an easy way to accomplish this? Xcode suggests that I cast it CGColorRef, but this does not work.

Comment: "Xcode suggests that I cast it CGColorRef, but this does not work." Xcode is right, though.

Comment: But it does not properly cast it. The color is black every time.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
groupPageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:203.0/255.0 green:17.0/255.0 blue:17.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor]
```

Comment: Because your values are no good. Everything above `1` is black. So this is black all the way.

Comment: The color components need to the on the range 0.0 - 1.0.

Comment: @matt Actually, that is white, not black.

Comment: @rmaddy whatever :) According to _1984_ they are the same anyway.

Comment: Ahh yes let me try that

Comment: My bad it works now using `modularLargeView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"BDBDBD"].CGColor;`. This was a really dumb question

Answer (score 0):

1st Ensure you imported

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

then add this 2 lines

```
groupPageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:203.0 green:17.0 blue:17.0 alpha:1].CGColor
groupPageView.layer.borderWidth =2.0;//default width =0 ; so if not set you will not see border colour
```